# Bash script to improve (if)

Tags: bash

I have this code:

```
if [[ $remaining_lines -gt 0 ]]; then
    for ((i=1; i<=$remaining_lines; i++)); do
    echo "0" >> $depth$ID\_depth_cp_tmp2
    done
fi
```

I want to add that else, do:

```
cp $depth$ID\_depth_cp_tmp $depth$ID\_depth_cp_tmp2
```

Can you help?
I tried adding that line prefixed by else, but it does not work...

Thanks!

Comment: pls show the entire script, including the `else` that you added, and what output / errors you see from running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this, although not 100% sure i'm understanding the question

```
if [[ $remaining_lines -gt 0 ]]; then
  for ((i=1; i<=$remaining_lines; i++)); do
    echo "0" >> $depth$ID\_depth_cp_tmp2
  done
else
  cp $depth$ID\_depth_cp_tmp $depth$ID\_depth_cp_tmp2
fi
```

I would run your script through shellcheck for quoting variables.